# I would like to understand how the following string is between 2 other strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Note this is my first post :)

I was working on a program and I saw some code that behaved unexpectedly. I know there is some implicit data conversions but I do not understand how it evaluates to true...

I ran the below code and it pulled 'Yes' instead of 'No' as I expected.

The code used GETDATE(). I changed it to cast today's date so the code can be ran on another day if needed just for this post.

```
SELECT  CASE 
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST('6/14/2016' AS DATETIME),101) BETWEEN '06/13/2014' AND '07/04/2014' 
            THEN 'Yes' 
        ELSE 'NO' 
    END
```

**Can someone explain to me the how it evaluates to true?**

Comment: Simple... When you convert date to string, then string can not be between dates. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are comparing the strings as your date is converted to `VARCHAR`.
And I bet the strings are sorted alphabetically. Let's test this theory:

```
declare @t table (a varchar(10))
insert into @t select '06/14/2016'
insert into @t select '06/13/2014'
insert into @t select '07/04/2014'

select a from @t order by a
```

This will output:

```
a
----------
06/13/2014
06/14/2016
07/04/2014

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Your 2016 date is the 2nd record, so it will fall between the other dates. If you want to treat those as dates, do not convert to `VARCHAR`. Then the other two dates will be converted to date type implicitly:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CAST('6/14/2016' AS DATETIME) BETWEEN '06/13/2014' AND '07/04/2014' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'NO' END
```

will output NO that you are expecting.

PS: To avoid unpredictable results, always declare/convert to `VARCHAR(n)` as `VARCHAR` conversion without specifying size uses the first string it encounters to determine size of the column in the result set and the rest may be truncated.

Comment: Good answer!  It explains why it would be between as well as pointing out the datatype issues and how to fix to expected behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation :) It makes sense. When I compare dates, I compare them as dates. The code I listed was in a program that was written a couple years ago (not by me)

Comment: By saying "you are comparing" I did not necessarily mean you as a person, but rather you as code :) Dealing with old code can be difficult, I know that very well.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're comparing different data types. If you just compare dates then you won't get an issue;

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN CAST('6/14/2016' AS DATETIME) BETWEEN '06/13/2014'
            AND '07/04/2014'
        THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'NO'
    END
```

It looks to me as you're basically treating these as text (varchar) it's going to do it character by character;

1. is 0 between 0 and 0, yep
2. is 6 between 6 and 7, yep
3. is / between / and /, yep
4. is 1 between 1 and 0, yep
5. is 4 between 3 and 4, yep

etc etc

Comment: Thank you for your explanation :) It makes sense

Comment: Until you get to the last character. 6 is not between 4 and 4.

Comment: I think @ajeh has explained it better than me, it's sorted alphabetically rather than by date.

Answer (score 0):

Finally result of `convert(cast(..))` is of `varchar` type. And constants in `between` are strings too. So Sql server has no choice but apply string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

It is doing a string compare rather than a date compare.  This is dangerous when the value is actually a date.  it is comparing the value of each ascii character.  You can use a table like this one (http://www.ascii-code.com/) to see the values of ascii characters.
06/13/2016
06/14/2016
07/04/2014

Comapare 1 column at a time.  The 0's are the same. 7 is greater than 6.  So 07/04/2014 is your largest value.  The first 2 dates are the same until you get to the 3/4 values.  3 is less than 4.  So 06/13/2016 is less than 06/14/2016.

Since the first character with a higher or lower value determines whether the string is greater or less than, it doesn't work with dates unless you format all your dates to yyyy-mm-dd format.  However, it is best to compare dates as dates rather than strings